# Can someone please help me ID these parts?

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to recreate this small creation, but don't have a parts list:

[image: small item]

Going from top down, here are my best guesses, but I'm not very good at this:

- 2654 (Black) Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom (Boat Stud)
- 4623 (Yellow) Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Arm Up (Horizontal Arm Length 6mm), qty 2
- [30151 (Yellow) Brick, Round 2 x 2 x 1 2/3 Dome Top](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=30151a&idColor=3#T=S&C=3&O=%7B%22color%22:3%7D)

I don't have any good guesses at to what the next two parts are. The "stem" looks almost like a **18654 Technic, Pin Connector Round 1L**, but they aren't available in yellow. Whatever it is, it connects to that 2 x 2 round plate that I can't ID either. The bottom piece I'm guessing is a:

- 4150 (Yellow) Tile, Round 2 x 2

Can anyone help me ID these parts more definitively? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure the piece directly under the Dome Top is just a 1x1 round brick, then a standard 2x2 round plate...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't familiar with the 1x1 round brick. I think you're right. Can you help me find a plain 2x2 round plate? [link](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=28) has ones with axle holes, but they don't have the 4 under stud holes as shown in the picture. (I'm relying on the 3d render...maybe it's wrong?)

Comment: As far as I am aware, *all* 2x2 round plates have those little holes under the studs and all have the axle hole in the middle.

Comment: Just found a photo. Yup, you're right. Accepting answer! Did my other items look right to you? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yep, everything else looks exactly right.